# Why excel change characters automatically? Trying to read excel in c# using OleDbDataAdapter

Tags: c#, excel, sqlite

I am trying to fetch data from excel to database SQLite using OleDbDataAdapter.
But as seen below, "-" sign automatically change to a square symbol.
Actually, it showing  "-" dash in excel and even in the sqlite database but if I try to search that MODEL it doesn't show. then I figure it out by copying in another text the sign is changing in square that's why it unable to search if I search "AKAA1-571" .

But I don't understand why is it changing? It shows something but its actually something else. How should I prevent this because I need "-" not something else so that I can fire query to search

Sorry, I am novice about excel, Unicode, characters. Please help me out.

Thanks.

[image]

Code:-
 #region Excel Connection
        private string ExcelConnectionOptions()
        {
            string strOpts = "";
            if (this.MixedData == true)
                strOpts += "Imex=1;";
            if (this.Headers == true)
                strOpts += "HDR=Yes;";
            else
                strOpts += "HDR=No;";
            return strOpts;
        }

```
    private string ExcelConnection()
    {

        string provider = @"Provider=Microsoft.Jet.OLEDB.4.0;" +
         @"Data Source=" + _strExcelFilename + ";" +
         @"Extended Properties=" + Convert.ToChar(34).ToString() +
         @"Excel 8.0;" + ExcelConnectionOptions() + Convert.ToChar(34).ToString();

        return provider;
    }
    #endregion
```

private bool SetSheetQuerySelect()
        {
            try
            {
                if (_oleConn == null)
                {
                    throw new Exception("Connection is unassigned or closed.");
                }

```
            if (_strSheetName.Length == 0)
                throw new Exception("Sheetname was not assigned.");

            _oleCmdSelect = new OleDbCommand(
                @"SELECT * FROM ["
                + _strSheetName
                + "$"
                + "]", _oleConn);

            return true;
        }
```

public System.Data.DataTable GetTable(string strTableName)

```
    {
        try
        {
            //Open and query
            if (_oleConn == null) Open();
            if (_oleConn.State != ConnectionState.Open)
                throw new Exception("Connection cannot open error.");
            if (SetSheetQuerySelect() == false) return null;

            //Fill table
            OleDbDataAdapter oleAdapter = new OleDbDataAdapter();
            oleAdapter.SelectCommand = _oleCmdSelect;
            System.Data.DataTable dt = new System.Data.DataTable(strTableName);
            oleAdapter.FillSchema(dt, SchemaType.Source);
            oleAdapter.Fill(dt);
```

### }

****After searching I found that in excel file that characters belong to different font/ character category. but looks similar, so When I read through OLEDBAdapter I want to replace these special characters by simple "-", But for reading, I am using OLEDbadapter as above, how to use replace string? ****

Comment: You did something in code, results didn't come out right, and then you asked for help... without showing code. Please help us to help you out.

Comment: I agree with KC Wong. Showing your input and output without code helps no one. My test gave me the dash as expected. I would look into how you are reading your data.

Comment: Hi wong, I have added code for OleDbDataAdapterexcel reading.

Answer (score 1):

Now that you know what's going on - the Excel data does not contain a simple minus/dash but instead something else (probably a soft-hyphen).

Then you can simply use String.Replace to swap the characters for data from that column:
https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/czx8s9ts(v=vs.110).aspx

**Edit:**

Since you are using OleDbDataAdapter, you probably want these instead:

https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms180059.aspx (UNICODE and CONVERT function)

https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms186862.aspx (REPLACE function)

Modify your SQL statement to replace the non-dash to dash.

Answer (score 0):

Somehow I try to solve this fetching data first in Datatable by using OLedbadapater.
Then changing  Data in that data column row by row. Like below

public DataTable trasnformTable(DataTable dt)
        {
            DataTable new_dt = dt.Copy();
            DataRow dr = new_dt.Rows[0];

```
        foreach(DataRow row in new_dt.Rows)
        {
            string Part_no = dr[0].ToString().Trim();
            string replaces_string = Regex.Replace(Part_no, @"[^a-zA-Z0-9\s]+", "-");
            dr[0] = replaces_string;
        }
```

return new_dt;
}

I don't know how to achieve this while fetching from excel because oledb just use select command to fetch in bulk direct to Datatable.